# do some calculations in a table using dropdowncombo

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, delphi-xe2, delphi-xe

I have a field in my database called 'Stock'. It displays how many items are there remaining for sale.Now I have a dropdowncombo with values like 1,2,3 etc... So now when I select an item in the grid and click the button SELL I would like the 'Stock' field of the item in question (in the grid) to decrease by the amount that was in the combo. So if the 'stock' was 100 and I sell 5 (dropdowncombo value) I would like the grid value to display now 95. I hope you know what I mean... I could do this with inserting a calculated field but I do not want to. Better an UPDATE ... Any ideas
something like UPDATE MyTable set STOCK = (Mytable.fieldbyname('stock').asInteger - dropdowncombo1.value)
dont have delphi here with me so unsure does this work on selected record in the grid...

Comment: Why wouldn't you set the field value through the dataset/table? `MyDataSet.FieldByName('Stock').AsInteger:=MyDataSet.FieldByName('Stock').AsInteger-5;`   And can you use paragrapsh etc. in your question?

Comment: because you can have any number from the dropdown combo

Comment: Then substitute that number from the dropdown combo with 5, 'FieldValue=FieldValue-DropdownNumber'.

Comment: you are not understanding the question...

Comment: I tried :abstable.FieldByName('stock').value := abstable.FieldByName('stock').value - cxcombobox1.text; but it seems I am getting dataset not in insert or edit mode.putting the table in edit mode does not solve the problem

Comment: Don't forget to convert the combobox text to an integer (inttostr). Also, *"the problem is not solved"* does not give *any* clue about *what* problem is not solved to someone who is at the other side of the screen <g>. Be specific as you can when you mention a problem (if you're getting an error what is it, if there's no error what or what does not happen etc..).

Comment: with some sort of magic it begun working , I have put abstable1.edit; and now it seeems to be working. you mean string to integer  here? strtoint(cxcombobox1.text); ?

Comment: Good job! Yes, it would be StrToInt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
abstable1.edit;
    abstable.FieldByName('stock').value := abstable.FieldByName('stock').value - strtoint(cxcombobox1.text);
    abstable1.Refresh;
```

This does the job ...